# ionic ios app stuck on splash screen - works in emulator not on iphone 5s device

Tags: javascript, ios, angularjs, cordova

I'm currently getting stuck on the splash screen when pushing to my iOS device. I've made sure to install ngCordova via bower install and all my ionic emulations are working as expected. Only when I deploy to an iOS device, does it get stuck on the splash screen. I've included the proper syntax for the splash screen in the config.xml file

```
<preference name="AutoHideSplashScreen" value="false" />
  <feature name="SplashScreen">
    <param name="ios-package" value="CDVSplashScreen" onload="true"/>
  </feature>
```

and I have the following in my main app.js file

```
.run(function($ionicPlatform, $cordovaSplashscreen, $timeout) {
  $ionicPlatform.ready(function() {
    $cordovaSplashscreen.hide();
```

(not including the rest of the content in the .run)

ionic version - 1.2.8
cordova version - 4.0.0

Here is the output in xcode for the working iOS emulation:

```
2014-11-10 17:09:15.150 endevr[94986:627339] DiskCookieStorage changing policy from 2 to 0, cookie file: file:///Users/drlightx3/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/7D2185B9-9897-41E8-B005-B0D35284F661/data/Containers/Data/Application/027864C5-CC64-4859-BCEA-48D8DD4B90A2/Library/Cookies/Cookies.binarycookies
2014-11-10 17:09:15.291 endevr[94986:627339] Apache Cordova native platform version 3.6.3 is starting.
2014-11-10 17:09:15.292 endevr[94986:627339] Multi-tasking -> Device: YES, App: YES
2014-11-10 17:09:15.304 endevr[94986:627339] Unlimited access to network resources
2014-11-10 17:09:15.631 endevr[94986:627339] [CDVTimer][splashscreen] 48.977017ms
2014-11-10 17:09:15.631 endevr[94986:627339] [CDVTimer][TotalPluginStartup] 49.114048ms
2014-11-10 17:09:15.691 endevr[94986:627339] Resetting plugins due to page load.
2014-11-10 17:09:15.886 endevr[94986:627339] Finished load of: file:///Users/drlightx3/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/7D2185B9-9897-41E8-B005-B0D35284F661/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/6EE8A114-222C-4903-88EC-9EEF8853B76C/endevr.app/www/index.html#/app/browse
```

Then, when I build to a an actual iPhone 5S I get the following:

```
2014-11-10 17:09:43.691 endevr[973:264078] DiskCookieStorage changing policy from 2 to 0, cookie file: file:///private/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/8512E3E3-FF06-4BDF-94DD-B999AD55ADCC/Library/Cookies/Cookies.binarycookies
2014-11-10 17:09:43.857 endevr[973:264078] Apache Cordova native platform version 3.6.3 is starting.
2014-11-10 17:09:43.859 endevr[973:264078] Multi-tasking -> Device: YES, App: YES
2014-11-10 17:09:43.868 endevr[973:264078] Unlimited access to network resources
2014-11-10 17:09:44.067 endevr[973:264078] [CDVTimer][splashscreen] 92.771947ms
2014-11-10 17:09:44.067 endevr[973:264078] [CDVTimer][TotalPluginStartup] 93.294024ms
2014-11-10 17:09:44.342 endevr[973:264078] Resetting plugins due to page load.
2014-11-10 17:09:44.696 endevr[973:264078] Finished load of: file:///private/var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/2BD18E5C-94C7-467D-83D5-617E3BD15434/endevr.app/www/index.html
```

looking at the last line of each output, it doesn't seem like ui-router's #/app/browse is getting hit on the iPhone 5S and I can't figure out why. When I run `ionic serve` and `ionic emulate ios` everything renders fine, but once I push it to my actual phone, it hangs on the splash screen.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Not sure what happened but what I ended up doing is creating a new clone of the remote repo and applied my splash screen related changes to the new instance on my local machine. then i executed the following:

`ionic platform rm ios
ionic platform add ios 
ionic build ios`

...and it was able to get out of the splash screen. hope this helps.

Comment: I didn't even get to splash screen. I stuck on dark screen when I got `****** RUN SUCCEEDED *****` in CLI.

Answer (score 6):

I had this setting set wrong:

```
  <preference name="AutoHideSplashScreen" value="true"/>
```

I had it set to false.  Switching to true cured it.